# In Ckeditor 5 Load editor data with suggestion tracked changes

Tags: javascript, ckeditor5

How to load editor data with suggestions and tracked changes. In ckeditor 5 we can load the content through setData or via rendering it directly to the page. I would to know if the editor have tracked changes how to load it back to the page.

https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/collaboration/track-changes/track-changes.html

```
DecoupledEditor
    .create( document.querySelector( '.editor' ), {
} )
.then( editor => {      
    window.editor = editor;            
    window.editor.setData(" data from somewhere with suggestion marker");           
} )
.catch( error => {
    console.error( error );
} );
```

I'm looking for the ckeditor 5 implementation for load tracked changes or suggestion markers

Comment: The collaboration tools might include some desired options: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/collaboration/real-time-collaboration/real-time-collaboration.html?docId=ead744b222292392562bb76b63e47660c, but also the `Mentions` plugin might be useful for auto-completion: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/mentions.html. Not sure, if all your desired features are available completely.